# How to get all connected sockets using socket.io-redis?

Tags: node.js, sockets, redis, socket.io, socket.io-redis

I have my multiple nodes running through socket.io-redis, Everything is working fine as I am emitting events to 1 server from another.

I want to get the full list of connected sockets on multiple servers together, as I have to manipulate their keys accordingly, Just like in simple socket.io's io object I get a hashmap with all the sockets.

Comment: I'm also looking to do this. Did you ever come up with a good solution?

Comment: I built a module which uses redis' pub sub, to get the number of connected sockets in that room.

Comment: Directly socket is not available, For the persistent information I used a database and to see the number of sockets in the room, I developed this module. Give me ur email, I shall send you the developed module.

Comment: I implemented the same yesterday with pub/sub. Thanks for the offer though.